# Перенос проекта с bitbucket на github

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Сам проект на bitbucket. Его нужно перенести на github. Сохранять коммиты и т.д. не нужно.

Получается нужно просто удалить папку .git просто и сделать git init заново и привязать проект к другому remote (от github), верно же понимаю? Или какие-то подводные камни могут еще быть? Что нужно проверить точнее еще перед этим.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/importing-your-projects-to-github

Comment: @Эникейщик Мне без коммитов, самый безопасный способ, так как проект на проде. То, что я описал - подойдет?

Comment: Да, должно подойти. В принципе же это просто создание нового проекта. Создать репу, инициализировать, добавить файлы, закомитить. Разницы же нет, один ли файл в новом проекте типа test.txt или стопицот штук.

Comment: `Сохранять коммиты и т.д. не нужно.` - это требование или "так проще"? Чтобы перенести, достаточно добавить еще один удаленные репо в конфиг. Делается это так: `git remote -v` - смотрим какие репы есть. Там будет битбакет. Заводим проект на Гитхабе, добавляем еще одну репу `git remote add github-repo {адрес новой репы}`. Выберите вместо github-repo более удачное. Можно и origin, но оно занято скорее всего, тогда переименуйте битбаковское название (файл `.git/config`). Потом `git push github-repo`. Зачем @Эникейщик посоветовал такой путь, я не понимаю.

Comment: PS. Наверное, я понял, вы хотите напрямую из bb в github, без клонирования на локальную машину. Тогда да, этот путь подойдет

Comment: @TotalPusher Требование, так как там 500 ненужных коммитов... Ну и вообще так проще, так как ваше предложение я не понял, а ломать ничего не хочется. Плюс надо разорвать связь с удаленным репозиторием с bb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Сохранять коммиты и т.д. не нужно

сохранить историю будет не только проще (см. ниже), но и полезнее (для последующей разработки):

1. изменяем url хранилища origin на url **пустого** (не содержащего ни одного коммита, в иной терминологии — ничем не «инициализированного») хранилища:

   ```
   $ git remote set-url origin git@github.com/…/…
   ```
2. отправляем туда историю:

   ```
   $ git push --all
   ```

вот и всё.

---

сравните с количеством действий для случая удаления локального хранилища со всей историей:

```
$ rm -rf .git
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit
$ git remote add origin git@github.com/…/…
$ git push --all
```

Answer (score 1):

Если не нужно сохранять коммиты, то действительно достаточно сделать следующее.

1. Удалить папку .git (rm -r -f .git)
2. Сделать заново git init
3. Затем сделать первый commit и remote куда надо, в моем случае - в новый репозиторий на Github